# Raspberry Pi won't boot after shutting down

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, boot-issues

I received a Raspberry Pi 3 today and made a 64 GB µSD card with the latest version of Raspbian Jessie (with Pixel). I plugged in an HDMI <> VGA adapter, then the 2.5 A-rated power supply, and it turned on. I played a few minutes with the Pi, which was working really great, then I stopped it at lunch time by pressing the "Shutdown" item in the Raspbian's menu.

The green light doesn't blink after shutdown, just the red light. But when I unplug the power supply and plug it back, the green light blinks randomly and the screen doesn't display anything (really nothing, not even a line of text or a colored square).

I formatted my SD card and wrote Raspbian Jessie to it: that worked fine and I was able to boot up my Pi. After I shut it down, no boot is possible again.

Do you have any idea of what happened or how to fix ?

Comment: Also my Pi is in a case and I only manipulate it with plastic gloves.

Comment: I installed Ubuntu Mate just before dinner and now it's working perfectly fine :) So I really wonder why this problem happens with Jessie ?

Comment: Could it be to do with a firmware update? Just wondering.

Comment: Is it possible you might have bumped the SD card, which resulted in the system not detecting it? In a situation such as yours: power down, remove the card, insert the card, power up.

Comment: @AndrewMorton : You mean I should update the Raspbian OS ? I took the latest version before writing it on the SD card.

Comment: @SiKing : I already tried this, after the two shutdown I removed the sd card and inserted it again, unplugged the power supply and plugged it a new time. I repeated this many times but it didn't work.

Comment: Do you have a display with HDMI to verify that this also happens with native HDMI output, VGA over HDMI requires some configuration which should be automatic but sometimes isn't.

Comment: Yes I have one, but now that works fine. I wonder why I had this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to decrease screen resolution at first boot. I came on same problem and solved in this wise.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same issue. 
My solution is to do an fsck on the to disks corresponding to the SD card.
This resumes to
fdisk -l to get the disk devices
fsck -y /dev/
fsck -y /dev/

Comment: You do that each time you shutdown ?

Answer (score 0):

To finish this question with an acceptable answer, here is the solution the questioner stated in the comments. He installed Ubuntu Mate and with this a reboot works without any problems.