# Raspberry Pi 3 Model B: not booting Raspbian after shutdown

Tags: boot-issues, raspbian-buster, shutdown

I installed the latest Raspbian on an SD card using Imager. The first boot: everything OK. Updates, installs and, rebooting: worked perfectly fine.

However, after shutdown, the screen is blank. After connecting the power cable red light is on, the green light goes on, then blinking, then off -- I am guessing it is loading from the SD card. But the screen is dead, it doesn't even show that anything is connected.

I do use an HDMI-VGA adapter, so would've loved to test on a pure HDMI connection but currently cannot do it (COVID-19, lockdown). Power supply: 2.5 A. There were neither rainbow nor red squares prior to shutdown.

The same problem happened when I installed Raspbian light, but I thought maybe I did something wrong with the configs, so tried with the full Raspbian.

It seems the same problem was reported [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/59402/raspberry-pi-wont-boot-after-shutting-down), but with no answer.

Comment: How big is the SD card?  I've seen long boot times on larger cards as the Pi expanded the partitions.  Took a few minutes from my memory.

Comment: @Andyroo 32 GB. At some point green light stop flashing - I assume it finished or stopped loading. Also, on reboot and on the first run it gave rainbow splash screen before showing loading screen. And reboot after the resize worked fine (and fast). The problem only occurs after shutdown.

Comment: Is it after every shutdown then?  Be interesting to load Stretch and see if that does the same.

Comment: how about you enable ssh, then if it is booting but without display (did you even try to ping the pi?), you can do some investigation of logs, dmesg etc

Comment: Plot thickens... I installed MATE instead of Raspbian since it was a solution for someone in the past. It worked for a while. I even did shutdown and start again: was fine. Things seem to brake after `sudo apt upgrade`.

Comment: Uncommenting `hdmi_force_hotplug=1` in user config allowed to boot. Resolution is wrong, but at least now I can investigate further.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I don't know what caused the problem. It seems that a kernel update might be a culprit. But I am not certain.

Two changes that allowed it to work (this on MATE now): in user config file (which is conveniently on FAT32 partition, so can be accessed from anything) I forced the use of HDMI with `hdmi_force_hotplug=1` -- I thought it might have been a problem since I am using HDMI-VGA adapter for my old monitor. This enabled video output. The resolution was off. So, I had to play with `hdmi_mode` to get it right (mode 36 was the right one for my screen).